Unity 6 WebGL what is throwing error in framework js
So I have paid for server hosting for my personal project and I wanted to add interactable app (made with unity WebGL) and as I never did WebGL outside of Itch.io and I am noob in terms of technical website stuff I tested every small change...
I started on 2022 something version of unity and got working full-windowed-screen with the minimal web template (by editing the index html file) and js code that tells the Unity app the full url where it reads the parameters (the things after the ?). So this all worked both on mobile and pc.
So after that I, obviously, wanted the splash screen gone, so I downloaded the V6 preview and the project updated and compiled without any errors. But after I uploaded it onto the public_html on my server I was greeted with black screen. So I went and in chronological order removed everything after there wasn't any scripts, only blank page with TMPro text. And nothing.
So I set the template to the basic (because the minimal doesn't show error/warning messages) and I got this(but as a popup window):
abort({}) at Error

at jsStackTrace (https://example.net/Build /Interact.framework.js:10:21611)

at stackTrace (https://example.net/Build /Interact.framework.js:10:21874)

at abort (https://example.net/Build/Interact .framework.js:10:992)

at https://example.net/Build/Interact .framework.js:10:19231


But I went and tested this on Itch.io and it worked... So my first thought was something is wrong with the server settings? But it worked on the previous version and the message links to a random (to me) part of the code that I didn't touch as it was generated by the unity itself.
As I stated I am beginner in the server/html/js stuff but I have no idea where to even start looking to fix this... If anyone knows If it's a Unity error(because it is preview ) or something wrong with the server?
Thanks.

I don't want to dismiss your question, but a) Unity 6 is in preview, for a reason, don't expect that anything works properly and b) this is not a question I'd personally ask on StackOverflow, because if it is an engine issue in a new preview version, Unity probably wants to hear about it, so why not post it in Unitys forums instead?

it can work fine, but, you need to have an apporpriate project, the right settings, and check the console log it should give more info on exactly what isnt working.  My guess would be you havent configured the wbeserver in the exact (and stupid) way unity needs, eg, it decided not to name files like build.wasm.br, but as build.wasm, but then has to tell the browser its .br.. so needs an odd configuration (covered by unity docs) - same for gzip
